# Facing issue while running Cucumber scenario

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am new to Cucumber and facing weird issue while running particular cucumber Scenario.
Below are two Scenario which I defined in my feature file.
first Scenario works without any problem but cucumber doesn't even consider second one while running test cases.

```
Scenario Outline: 
1.Validate create  functionality

Given user is on "Home" screen
When click on Create
Then create screen should render


Scenario Outline: 
2.Validate create  Name,Description,Start Date


    Given user is on create screen
    When user enters following values:

            |  Name                   | dummyName       |
            | Desc                    | dummyDesc@#     |
            | Date                    | ghgh            |   

    Then there should be error message on the screen.
```

**Below is the feature implementation method in java**

Scenario 1.

```
@Given("^user is on \"([^\"]*)\" screen$")
    public void homeScreen(String home) throws Throwable {
        //someCode
    }

@When("^click on Create$")
    public clickCreate() throws Throwable {
        //someCode
    }

@Then ("^create screen should render$")
    public void createRender() throws Throwable {
        //someCode
    }
```

Scenario 2.

```
@Given("^user is on create screen$")
    public void crateScreen() throws Throwable {
        //someCode
    }


@When("^user enters following values :$")
public void EnterValues(Map<String,String> map) throws Throwable {
        //someCode
    }

@Then("^there should be error message on the screen.$")
public void errorMessage() throws Throwable {
        //someCode
    }
```

Why Scenario is not invoked by Cucumber?

Environment- Cucumber,Selenium,JAVA

Comment: Thanks for reply but it doesn't show any error,but scenario 2 is not getting executed.

Comment: Where is your runner?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not using any placeholders around variable names used in example table.In fact I see lot of gherkin syntax issues anyways in your code.Try this:

```
Scenario Outline: Validate Input Fields
 Given user is on create screen
 When user enters following values <createName>,<Description>,<StartDate>
 Then should receive this <ErrorMessage>

 Examples:
   | createName| Description| StartDate| ErrorMessage|
   | DummyName| dummyDesc@#| ghgh| Invalid Date Entered |
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but my code is working if i change "Scenario Outline" to "Scenario" and Thanks for highlighting gherkin syntax issues will try to resolve those as well

Comment: If you use Scenario Outline: you need to have an Examples: so if this is not the case, cucumber will not work as expected. if i understand yor feature correctly, you should use the normal Scenario: and not the Outline variant